# How to test hypothesis on the composition of CAPM portfolios

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, distributions, finance

I'm facing two different portfolios in CAPM framework derived as
$$\hat{\omega}_P=\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}\frac{E(r)-r_f}{H}(\hat{\mu}-\iota'r_f)$$
on the same assets but, for example, on different time samples or on the same assets but one.

I recall that $H=(\hat{\mu}-\iota'r_f)\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}(\hat{\mu}-\iota'r_f)$ and $\iota$ is a vector of ones; moreover $r_f$ is the risk free rate, $E(r)$ is return the investor wants to obtain so they are deterministic.

I'd like to test (if possible) whether the weights of the two portfolios are statistically equal or not. I was thinking I need the distribution of the weights and proceed as usual for hypothesis testing, because the portfolio derived above is a function of the estimated returns distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$.

My problem is that I don't how I can calculate the theoretical distribution of $\omega_P$.

How can I proceed?